# Retrieve list of pages by ID list in Notion API

Tags: notion-api

I'm developing a project using Notion API and I need to get a list of pages given the relative id list.

I basically have a list of ids saved locally and I want to get the list of relative pages.

I already tried to use the [Query a database](https://developers.notion.com/reference/post-database-query) endpoint but it seems that it doesn't support filtering by the ID field.

The easy solution is to make N calls to the [Retrieve a page](https://developers.notion.com/reference/retrieve-a-page) endpoint, but of course this wouldn't be optimal.

Does anyone knows a better solution?

Comment: I'm having this same exact problem, did you find the solution for this? For now I'm also doing N calls.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I didn't found any better solution than doing N separated calls.